# cross platform MultiByteToWideChar

Tags: c++, boost

Is `boost::locale::conv::to_utf`([here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/locale/doc/html/group__codepage.html#gaef8fb7771dce60511d081770547a4139)) same as the windows api `MultiByteToWideChar` ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least they differ in possible target encodings:

- `MultiByteToWideChar` converts various code pages to UTF-16
- Boost [Character Set Conversions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/locale/doc/html/charset_handling.html) can convert to UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32

Also set of supported source encoding may differ.

If the question is whether boost function uses `MultiByteToWideChar` / `WideCharToMultiByte` when running on Windows, then probably you should peek into the `boost` implementation, but I expect that no. And anyway this is a sort of implementation detail that might change, and should not matter.

Comment: makes sense. What does `from_utf` do? is it same as `WideCharToMultiByte` ?

Comment: I think yes, again assuming you pass `wchar_t` range to `from_utf`